# margin top different display between chrome and mozilla

Tags: css, google-chrome, mozilla

i have trouble dispay with chrom and Mozilla whene i use margin top with %, 
In mozilla the we show Distance between the head and the body, but in chrom it's perfetct.

for the result show it in drop box plz 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/99bd5kc03mpvuim/AAAoFb6AX2LbwbXvatIV2hyna?dl=0

what can I do to fix this?

```
.manage-listing-nav{
    width: 224px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;left: 0%;
    margin-top:31%;
    /*-moz-margin-top: 30% !important; /* for mozilla */
}
```

Comment: Did you use a reset?

Comment: if you set it to an exact pixel amount (30px) does it still do that?

Comment: Try a simple reset like this `* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}`

Comment: no i didn't use reset because i use worpress

Comment: however for the px not work

Comment: Reset will not fix the issue so ignore any thoughts on that. You need to show a minimal, usable example of the problem and your CSS snippet is not enough. What is the size set of the parent element? Is it position:relative?